# Detect character combinations from a text file and assign the entire line as a variable in Python

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to detect a list of usernames that is dumped from another script and find if they contain a specific subset of characters (_x and _y at the end). Every username is on a separate line, and formatted as "user", "user_x" or "user_y". What I want to do is detect specifically the _x and _y users and make that the value for Test_X for another script. What I have so far:

```
with open('user_list.txt', 'r') as file:
  lines = file.read()
  test_user = file.read().rstrip('\.n)
```

I'm pretty new to Python overall and I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

As each username is on a separate line, you can loop over the lines in the file, check whether the line ends with the characters you want and then save the username in list(s).

You can then do what you would like with said list but we'll need more info with how you want to deal with it to help you further with that part. I've given an example function below.

As for how to do this, use the built in [str.endswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) function:

```
def func():
    users = [] # all users
    x_users = [] # only users with name ending in '_x'
    y_users = [] # only users with name ending in '_y'
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f: # loop over lines in file
            line = line.rstrip() # remove end-of-line characters
            users.append(line) # all users
            if line.endswith('_x'):
                x_users.append(line) # only _x
            elif line.endswith('_y'):
                y_users.append(line) # only _y

    # Can now do whatever you'd like with the three lists that were created
    # In this case, return the x and y lists as a tuple of lists
    return (x_users, y_users)
```

In the above example, your other script can then call this function to access `x_users` and `y_users`.